Solving PDEs in MATLAB for a Simulink model
I'm currently working on a model of Metal Hydrides absorption/desorption in simulink. The model is based on 3 partial differential equations in which there is a spatial coordinate r (along the radius of a cylidrical tank) other than the time t, namely:
mass balance equations
and
energy balance equation.
The first two equations are in function of the densities of the gas (_g) and solid (_s), which are both function of P(r,t) and T(r,t), while the energy equations is directly function of T.
is it possible to solve them in the matlab environment?
Each of the terms fundamentally are functions of the pressure P(r,t) and temperature T(r,t), variables wrt which i want to solve (i.e.: the goal is to see how P and T vary). I imagine the equations are to be solved simultaneously since they are coupled, and each term contains both P and T, and for exaple the term 'v' contains the partial derivative of P wrt r.
These are the conditions:
initial conditions,
boundary conditions, where the last boundary condition is due to an external cooling source.
I tried using pdepe but the problems are:

the first 2 equations i understand how they could be written in the right form even though i would like to solve for P(r,t) which is inside the density terms /rho, along with the term T, and i wonder if I have to rewrite the equations in some way.

the temprature equations I have no idea how to write it I do not find anything online.


Also, in the paper that I am following, they transform the first two equations as this, and the second as this, with Theta being this. But I do not understand how they transformed it and even how I could solve them in the new form.
I can provide any additional inormation if needed, including the paper I am referring to.
Thank you

Please proof read your question and note that LaTeX is not rendered on this site. [Edit] your question to make it more legible using the available formatting options or rendering the equations elsewhere and including them as images, although markdown is usually preferable, especially when you can write the equations as code which you've tried and have a specific issue with

The question is not really visible. Does transformation of coordinates help in your case.

I have now edited the question so tell me if you are able to see. What do you mean by tranformation of coordinates?
